# Setting an imageview as an icon on a button

Tags: button, javafx

I was trying to write a JavaFX application; I wanted to put images in my icons and make them transparent, so that you would click on the `ImageView` without seeing the button.

[Here i have the scenebuilder were i got the imageview and in the button in style i said: -fx-background-color transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ4BF.png)

[Then we have here the preview of what is going to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaVb7.png)

[And lastly, this is the application when i run it on netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2atd.png)

Comment: It is my fist post so im sorry if the format is awkward or something, not used to ask here yet.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO! Are you trying to put images in ImageViews and then set these ImageViews in Button (with transparent background)? In that case, the preview on SB seems ok. When you run on NetBeans, does NB throws any exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i wanted to put images in my icons and make them transparent so you clicked on the imageview and you didn't saw the button.

Just call `btn.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);` to remove the default background of the button.

eg:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33949.png");
    iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
    iv.setFitWidth(60);
    Button btn = new Button("", iv);
    btn.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Produces:

[image]